# Box Windows V2 SDK with Box.V2.JWTAuth for C# web application

Tags: c#, box-api, jwt

I am trying to use Box.V2.JWTAuth to create a server to server box api call.

i use the code from git:

```
var boxConfig = new BoxConfig(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, ENTERPRISE_ID, JWT_PRIVATE_KEY, JWT_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD, JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_ID);
var boxJWT = new BoxJWTAuth(boxConfig);

var adminToken = boxJWT.AdminToken();
var adminClient = boxJWT.AdminClient(adminToken);
```

when Debug in Visual Stuido, run through to create the new BoxJWTAuth(boxConfig), always show "PEMReader.cs not found".

I compare to the sample in https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2, and found out in the Box.V2.Samples.JWTAuth reference, the Box.V2.JWTAuth have a PEMpasswordFinder class, but the one i install from nuget don't have this class.

Is that the reason BoxJWTAuth can't create in my code?

Any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: If you view the disassembly, it is referring to bouncy castle, a crypto package. PEM is your key file so I assume it's trying to read your key file but I haven't seen how you can point it anywhere. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The NuGet package for Box.V2 is out-of-date.  I found that I had to download the code from GitHub and pull out both of the projects needed (Box.V2.JWTAuth and Box.V2) and include them in my project.

I would also point out that their example doesn't adhere to most Enterprise security standards because certificates should be stored in certificate store, which requires a PFX file (not a PEM file).  Had they followed this a approach, they would NOT have needed Bouncy Castle to read the PEM file since the X509Store class can read them from the certificate store and return a X509Certificate2 instance.  Furthermore, the X509Certificate2 can read a PFX files directly as well, but CANNOT read PEM files.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to David's answer, once you add both projects you can do something along these lines to use the PEM file.

```
   private static BoxClient BoxClient(string user)
    {
        var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/private_key.pem");
        var privateKey = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        var boxConfig = new BoxConfig(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, ENTERPRISE_ID, privateKey, JWT_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD,
            JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_ID);
        var boxJWT = new BoxJWTAuth(boxConfig);

        var userToken = boxJWT.UserToken(user); 
        var userClient = boxJWT.UserClient(userToken, user); 
        return userClient;
    }
```